# Remove all special characters except apostrophe

Tags: ruby, regex

I know there are similar questions. However, I cannot find one exactly phrased as mine. I don't understand or study regex and this is why I need to ask this question.

I have a method in which I want to do the above (title):

```
def alternate_words(string)
  x = string.each {|char| char.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')}
end
```

This regex proves to work for most special characters. However it does remove apostrophes and I want to keep mine. How can we change this?

Comment: `/[^0-9A-Za-z']/`

Comment: Time to get reading:) http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to do so you should consider using POSIX bracket-expressions or `\p{`} constructs rather than the English-centric `0-9A-Za-z`. Here that would be `/[^[:alnum:]']/` or `/[^\p{Alnum}']/`.
 (Search for both in the doc [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html).) You'll thank yourself if you have to port your apps to support multiple languages.

Comment: Is `string` actually an array of strings?

Answer (score 4):

Just add the apostrophe to the negated character class:

```
def alternate_words(string)
  x = string.each {|char| char.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z']/, '')}
  #                                           ---^---
end
```